# Checking columns for blanks

Tags: sql, ms-access, multiple-columns

I have 2 columns: `colA` and `colB`. I want a query that would retrieve values from `colA`, but if there is a blank in the column, I want to retrieve it from `colB` and vice versa. I should note that `colA` must have precedent over `colB` in the case that there are 2 values in both columns. I know in SQL server you can use the `isNull` function but I can't seem to find the equivalent for MS Access.

Comment: use the IIF function

Answer (score 2):

```
select Nz(ColA, ColB) from table1
```

Or you can use `IIF(IsNull(ColA),ColB,ColA)`